How to pass parameters to Custom Web API Skill
I am trying to use Custom Web API skill in Azure AI Search from the Azure portal directly. It has the following template :

If I have to pass parameters to the api, for example a list and a boolean value along with some input property which is coming from /document, how can I do that ?
I have tried to look at various places but did not find any example for this scenario`
Looked at Azure documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api and  github repos but could not find anything.

As of know you can not pass the values which are not present in index.
Only index fields are passed as inputs, which are in the context document/.
So, anything you want to send to custom web api skill set, use httpHeaders
and read it in custom web api.
Below is the sample for skillset.
{
    "skills": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
        "name": "myCustomSkill",
        "description": "This skill calls an Azure function, which in turn calls TA sentiment",
        "uri": "https://indexer-e2e-webskill.azurewebsites.net/api/DateExtractor?language=en",
        "context": "/document",
        "httpHeaders": {
            "DateExtractor-Api-Key": "foo"
        },
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "contractText",
            "source": "/document/content"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "contractDate",
            "targetName": "date"
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
}

Like this you send your Boolean and list in strings, then read it.
Below i used python function app as custom web api.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
 
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
 
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    for header, value in req.headers.items():
        logging.info(f"Header: {header}, Value: {value}")
    
    # Retrieve a specific header (example: 'User-Agent')
    user_agent = req.headers.get('User-Agent', 'Unknown')
    DateExtractor_api = req.headers.get('DateExtractor-Api-Key','Unknown')
    
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')
 
    if name:
        response_message = f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    else:
        response_message = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
    
    # Include the User-Agent header in the response
    return func.HttpResponse(
        f"{response_message}\nUser-Agent: {user_agent}",
        status_code=200
    )


